# Row height in a gallery

Tags: gallery, powerapps

Im pretty new at powerapps.

Anyway I have a gallery where I have a variable which contains questions and another row which contains the answer to the questions. On a few questions the answer is not text but rather an image. When the user scrolls through the gallery I would like the row column height for the Image answer to be bigger than the row column height where there is text. I tried in a million ways with no success.

If anyone can help me and show me the way . I would really appreciate it

If you do not have the answer thank you as well for taking the time to read my post

Thank you

Ive tried to crate a text label (ie Label4_Height)which determines if the result is an image or text ans setting that variable to a value
In the height of the Text variable or Image variable i set its height to the value of the Label4_Height variable

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Flexible Height gallery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Row height of Gallery is defined by TemplateSize property of the Gallery.
Default TemplateSize is the height of the Gallery.
When you increase/decrease the TemplateSize it will automatically reflect the row height.

Hope this helps!!